# SharePoint 2010 - Group by two columns at once

Tags: 2010, grouping

I'd like to group a view on two columns at the same time.  The first column contains a serial number.  The second column, **Related To**, is a lookup pointing to the **Serial Number** column.  What I'm looking for is a way to group the view so that any items with EITHER a serial number or a matching value in the **Related To** column are grouped together within the view.

Example:

```
Item     Direction     SN     Related To
Hiya     Incoming      123    
This     Incoming      234
Is       Outgoing      345    123
An       Outgoing      456    234
Example  Outgoing      567    123
```

The result of this would be something like the following:

```
+ 123
    Hiya
    Is
    Example
+ 234
    This
    An
```

For now I'm working under the assumption that Incoming items have a serial number only, while Outgoing will have both **SN** and **Related To** filled in.  I'm assuming SPD is needed to get something like this to happen.  Do you have ideas on how to make this happen?

Comment: In your example, the direction of the non-related items is incoming, and the related items is outgoing.  Is this always going to be the case?

Comment: That's my understanding right now, yes.  I have a feeling if I can get this working, a future change might be manageable; I'm just not sure how to get started doing this.

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to condionally group by columns, that is not possible Out of the box.

Edit: For lookup columns:

I would advise you build this using JavaScript. However, if that's not an option for you, I would create a single field column (not a calculated column) and create a SPDesigner workflow that runs on edit and uses the same logic.

If you're not using lookup columns you can use the below:

1. Create a new calculated column called SnCalculated (choose whatever name you want)
2. The formula should be something like this IF([Direction] <> 'Incoming', [Related To], [SN]). This says "If direction does not equal Incoming use Related To, otherwise use Sn"
3. Group by the calculated column

Comment: This was what I had in mind as well, but unfortunately lookup columns aren't available in Calculated columns

Comment: @Hutch updated answer, you can use JS or SpDesigner WF

Comment: yup SPD workflow works.  You would want to trigger it on add as well as edit I think.

Comment: actually edit would suffice as I think it runs in both cases